# SBT Broken Pipe

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been avoiding using SBT since the support in intellij for maven has always been far superior, plus I don't see much advantage in SBT; but I figure why fight the masses.

So one of my open source projects I've converted over to SBT. Now when I run tests (approx 1000 test cases), I get OOMs. Ok so I've tried

```
fork in Test := true

javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Xmx2048m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m")
```

Ok so my OOMs go away but now I get

```
sbt.ForkMain$Run$RunAborted: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run.write(ForkMain.java:114)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run$1.info(ForkMain.java:132)
```

Seems to be in different places each time.

These tests all pass if I'm building via maven (scala test maven plugin).

Help me Obi-wan or SBT lovers.

Edit: Adding env details

sbt 0.12.4
java 7.25
scala 2.10.2

Comment: I wonder if you are still getting an OOM in the forked process and when that happens, you get a broken pipe. Are you able to monitor the forked process with visualvm or similar and see if after a GC the memory goes down?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll see if I can connect to the forked process.